# How to return large Json in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1, coreclr

In classic asp.net in order to return large json data i enable it web.config

```
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

and then also set the max length in action method

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
        var data = _service.GetData();
        var json = Json(data);
        json.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        return json;
}
```

what is equivalent in ASP.NET core? In asp.net core I don't see `JsonResult` has `MaxJsonLength` proeprty

Comment: are you hitting a limit/getting an error or somethin?

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using Kendo spreadsheet to show data, and it was showing only 200 rows. and i though like classic asp.net, the `asp.net core` also has limitation of how much data can be serialized and send back to client. But anyway i found the issue, kendo spreadsheet by default shows only 200 rows. i changed the settings in kendo spreadsheet and it worked.