# ASP.Net Core 2.0 API Response hangs with large json payload

Tags: postman, asp.net-core-2.0, httpresponse

I am working on an ASP Net Core 2.0 Web API. One of my endpoints returns a json object that includes a text field that can be fairly large. When this field gets around 10Mb in size the controller just stops until the timeout is hit. When I debug, I see that the json object is created in my business logic and passed to the endpoint controller but the controller just stops right after it receives json object with no error and doesn't return to the caller until the request finally times out. I increased my requestTimeout to 20 mins even though the business logic generates the json object in less than 2 minutes. It just hangs until the 20 minute timeout is hit.

Here is my controller action;

[EXAMPLE 1]

```
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetFile")]
    public async Task<FileResponseDto> GetFile([FromRoute] int companyId, [FromRoute] int siteId, [FromRoute] int FileId, 
        [FromHeader(Name = "Accept")] string mediaType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var fileResponseDto = _fileBll.GetFile(companyId, siteId, fileId, HttpContext);

        // This is the point where the controller appears to hang

        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => fileResponseDto, cancellationToken);

    }
```

and my DTO object;

```
public class FileResponseDto
{
    public string ReferenceId { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string ProcessingFile { get; set; }
}
```

The property that is the large string is the ProcessingFile property in the FileResponseDto class.

This works fine until my ProcessingFile property gets to around 30K lines (about 10Mb) and then the controller just hangs after it completes the line;

```
var fileResponseDto = _fileBll.GetFile(companyId, siteId, fileId, HttpContext);
```

At this point, my assumption was that I have hit some limitation in the size of the json object. So, to test, I changed my controller so that it returns a file instead, like what is shown below;

[EXAMPLE 2]

```
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetFile")]
    public async Task<FileContentResults> GetFile([FromRoute] int companyId, [FromRoute] int siteId, [FromRoute] int fileId, 
        [FromHeader(Name = "Accept")] string mediaType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var fileResponseDto = _fileBll.GetFile(companyId, siteId, fileId, HttpContext);

        var outputFile = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileResponseDto.ProcessingFile);

        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            new FileContentResult(outputFile, new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet))
            {
                FileDownloadName = fileResponseDto.Filename
            }, cancellationToken);

    }
```

Making this change works and I can receive a file download dialog popup and a successful file if I select "Send and Download" in Postman.

So, this leads me to believe that there is something size related to the json object being transferred in the first example.

However, web searches have not turned up anything useful on this issue, which makes me think that perhaps I am missing something here.

I did find [this link in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271054/how-to-return-large-json-in-asp-net-core) and tried it by using...

```
var outfileJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject<fileResponseDto>;
```

outfileJson.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

but outfileJson did not have a MasJsonLength property.

So.. any ideas?

**EDIT 6/8/18**

After 2 days, 22 views and no actual responses. I figured something must be wrong with my approach. I realized that I did not mention that I was performing these tests in Postman, which is where I was seeing the problem. After further digging, I found a [post on GitHub](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3589) that seemed to be related to what I was experiencing in Postman (the hang on large response payload). It seems that Postman has a limit in the number of "rows" it returns in the response. The GitHub post was a feature request to increase the number of rows.

I am not sure how to handle this StackOverflow question now. Since I didn't mention Postman in the original post, I don't feel right just answering my own question. So, I guess I will leave it as is for a couple of days to see if anyone chimes in with their thoughts before I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the was, if fact, an issue with Postman and the size of the response payload it currently supports. If, instead of selecting Send, I select Send and Download in Postman, It will download the JSON object and pop up a dialog box to allow me to save it to my local drive. Then when I examine the file, I can see the json object is correctly formatted and transferred.

I confirmed that it was only a Postman issue and not a .NET HttpResponse issue by performing the API call in a .Net client application, which was able to receive the Json object without error.